# r - ggplot - y-scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I would like to 'zoom in' in my ggplot, because as you can see, one can't see too much. I know that I could change the limits of the y-axis, but I am supposed to show the whole scale.

I tried a lot, changing the breacks, etc. but nothing works. Does anyone know how do minimizes the spaces between the labels of the y-axis so one can see a litte more (as in picture two, but with the whole y-scale)?

Here is my code so far:

```r
ggplot(
data = data_plan_kl
, mapping = aes(
y = Mean
, x = ISTSOLL
)
)+
geom_point(
mapping = aes(
colour = regel_foerder
, shape = regel_foerder
)
, alpha = 30
)+
geom_errorbar(
mapping = aes(
colour = regel_foerder
, ymin = lo
, ymax = hi
)
, linetype = 1
, show.legend = FALSE
, width = 0.25
, alpha = .5
)+
labs(
x = 'Aktuelle und gewünschte Aufgabenverteilung'
, y = 'Zuständigkeit'
, colour = 'Lehramt'
, shape = 'Lehramt'
) + ggtitle('Planung der Verhaltensförderung auf Klassenebene') +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(1,5), breaks = seq(0,5,1))
```

On can't see much, but the y-axis is complete

[image: One can't see much, but the y-axis is complete]

One can see more, but the y-axis is not complete

[image: One can see more, but the y-axis is not complete]

Comment: It seems as if *"I would like to 'zoom in'"* is directly and clearly in opposition with *"I am supposed to show the whole scale"*.

Comment: As an aside, consider indenting your code. It's very hard to read.

Comment: Another side: on StackOverflow, code blocks are demarcated by "fences" which are triple backticks `\`\`\``; while you did include them in your question, *they must be on lines of their own* with no code on the same line. The only exception to this rule is that the first may include a "language-hint", such as `\`\`\`r` or `\`\`\`lang-r`; the closing "fence" must always be three backticks alone. (This includes no leading blank-space.) I suggested an edit to your question to clear this up (which revealed previously hidden code, `ggplot(`). See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more help.

Comment: Have a look at the `ggbreak` package, which might offer a compromise solution